# NSString Propertylist issue

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, property-list

What is the best way to validate whether a NSString is a propertyList or not? If I call NSString's -propertyList method it will throw an exception if it cannot parse the string.

Comment: @phix23 I'd prefer validating the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `+propertyListWithData:options:format:error:` on [`NSPropertyListSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to attempt to parse the data, it can pass you back an `NSError` object with some diagnostics if it can't. For example:

```
NSString *plist = ...;
NSError *e = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
id obj = [NSPropertyListSerialization 
    propertyListWithData:[plist dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                 options:NSPropertyListImmutable
                  format:&format
                   error:&e];
```